# attempting to login dockerhub but get error "Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

#### Issue Description:

I'm encountering an error in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, specifically during the execution of a job. The error message is:

```
Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

my gitlab ci/cd:

```
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: docker:24.0.6
  services:
    - docker:24.0.6-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - echo $DOCKER_USER
    - echo "$DOCKER_PASS" > ./my_psw.txt
    - cat ./my_psw.txt
  script:
    - mkdir -p /root/.docker
    - cat ./my_psw.txt | docker login --username genadigeno --password-stdin
    - docker build --tag genadigeno/emergency-service:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push genadigeno/emergency-service:$IMAGE_TAG
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
  after_script:
    - echo "" > ./my_psw.txt
    - cat ./my_psw.txt
    - docker logout
  except:
    - main
```

I have tried to login via `docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS` but same error.
actually when I run `echo $DOCKER_USER or $DOCKER_PASS` does not printed anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device` error occurs when you use --password-stdin but no password is supplied.

Looks like `DOCKER_USER` and `DOCKER_PASS` variables are setup at project/group level variables. And they are marked as "protected" variables. Hence they can be used only on protected branches(for example `main`) or protected tag.

Your pipeline runs on a branch other than "main".

```
  except:
    - main
```

So on a non protected branch a protected variable value will be empty and hence the error from docker

**Solution:**

If you want to use these variables on branches other than main then do the following

Under Setting->CI/CD settings->CI/CD Variables "edit" the variable `DOCKER_USER` and `DOCKER_PASS` and uncheck the Flag "Protect variable" and save.